# Redirect in authClient.js Admin on Rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have `authClient.js` file as below:

```
export default (type, params) => {
if (type === AUTH_LOGIN) {
    return UserLoginService.signIn(params)
}
if (type === AUTH_LOGOUT) {
    // ...
}
if (type === AUTH_ERROR) {
    // ...
}
if (type === AUTH_CHECK) {
    return localStorage.getItem('token') ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject({ redirectTo: '/no-access' });
}
return Promise.reject('Unkown method');};
```

In authentication services, after user signed up, I create temporary password and send it to user via email. I require user to change their password in the first login.

In `UserLoginService.signIn()`, if it's the first login, I do this `reject({ code: 'NewPasswordChallenge' });`

Is there any way to redirect to `/change-password` page if type is `AUTH_LOGIN`? like when type is `AUTH_CHECK`?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily for now. You might be able to address this by implementing a [custom saga](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#customsagas) which would be triggered on the `USER_LOGIN_FAILURE` action. It won't prevent the notification display though.

However, this could be a nice addition I think. You're welcome to make a PR about it :)

Comment: `USER_LOGIN_FAILURE` - How and where do you define this action ? Also in the sample link, where is definition for `BITCOIN_RATE_RECEIVED` i.e. how is this action being registered ?

Comment: I don't see `BITCOIN_RATE_RECEIVED` anywhere in your example.

Comment: `import { USER_LOGIN_FAILURE } from 'admin-on-rest';`

Comment: `BITCOIN_RATE_RECEIVED` is in `your` sample link which you supplied in `your` answer, So, how do you register such custom events to write sagas which are **not** present by default in `AOR`?

Comment: Also pls correct me if I am wrong - `custom sagas` are those tiny notification which pop up from the below. right ? Is there not a way to write n hook custom dedicated reactjs pages w.r.t such custom exceptions ?

Comment: Not at all. sagas are functions which handle side effects of actions, for example notifications. The `BITCOIN_RATE_RECEIVED` in the example is just an example of custom redux action which might exists in your code (sorry about that).

Comment: `for example notifications` <------- so that is what I meant in context of `AOR`? Which notification example are you referring to w.r.t `AOR`?

Comment: I meant: `notifications` is an example of side effects.